# How to revert from Angular-cli to Angular without cli for server-side rendering with Angular Universal

Tags: angular-cli, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a large-scale application built using the Angular-cli and I really need some server-side rendering for the sake of better SEO.

I have tried integrating Universal within my current cli project, but had no success and ran into bug after bug. I have also tried to use the Universal-cli (https://github.com/devCrossNet/universal-cli), but also without success. Lot's of cryptic errors.

I'm about to revert to using Angular without the cli so I can plug in Angular Universal without the trouble caused by the cli, but I want to ask for feedback first.

Do you have any recommendations for an easy way to revert from Angular-cli to Angular without the cli on an existing project? Or is my approach all wrong, and I should keep the cli and integrate a different server-side solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-cli can now compile your ng generated code into universal coce. You won't have to revert your build from using the cli to webpack.

The full how-to guide can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering)

Great news for us devs that have an angular-cli generated project!